# Rabbit MQ:Unable to login usin new user

Tags: rabbitmq

I have setup rabbitmq on aws ec2 and I was trying to login to web interface.Since Rabbitmq allows guest users to login from localhost only I created one more user tried to login from that but it always shows me the prompt window

I am trying to login from remote machine.Rabbit mq is running on ubuntu Machine.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem I was having special characters in my password I changed the password it worked